# A non-absolute norm function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vectors, normed-spaces

For vector norms: $$||x|| = || -x ||$$ Is it always the case, or there exists some norms such that a vector and its negative or the absolute (all elements with modulo) have different norm value?

Comment: It is a defining property of a real or complex vector space norm (see the wiki info for the tag) that $||ax|| = |a| ||x||$.  So you can work out the implication for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In a normed vector space, one of the axioms on the norm is that for all scalars $\alpha$ and vectors $x$, $\|\alpha x\| = |\alpha| \|x\|$. So you will always have
$$\|-x\| = |-1|\|x\| = \|x\|.$$

Comment: what about absolute vectors? Is the norm of the vector always equal to the norm of its absolute vector?

Comment: @MahmudAllahverdiyev:  I'm not sure what you mean by "absolute vectors".  It doesn't seem to be a standard term in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

One of the axioms of a norm is that $\Vert \alpha x\Vert=|\alpha|\Vert x\Vert$ for all vectors $x$ and all scalars $\alpha$. Therefore, we will always have $$\Vert -x\Vert=|-1|\Vert x\Vert=\Vert x\Vert$$

Comment: what about absolute vectors? Is the norm of the vector always equal to the norm of its absolute vector?

Comment: @MahmudAllahverdiyev what do you mean by "absolute vector".

Comment: For example, if v = (-2, 3, -5), then absolute vector of v is (2, 3, 5).

Comment: If you're just working in $\mathbb C^n$ for instance with the standard norm, then yes.

Comment: But for which fields and which functions the property does not hold?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how you define the absolute vector on an arbitrary vector space because it seems that you need the vectors to be in $\mathbb C^n$. What is your general definition of an absolute vector?

Comment: I mean just taking the absolute value for each element of the vector.

Comment: Yeah, so you are assuming that the vector space is $\mathbb F^n$ for some field $\mathbb F$ in which you have the notion of absolute value. In this case, under the standard "dot product" induced norm, the norm of a vector will equal the norm of its absolute value vector.

Comment: The original version of my question is as following: The norm is called absolute if  ‖x‖=‖|x|‖  holds for any vector x, where  x=(x1,…,xn)(transpose)  and  |x|=(|x1|,…,|xn|)(transpose). Give an example of a norm which is not absolute.